# Conditional formatting based on cells and rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Hi I am trying to Conditional format duplicate entries based on "if a cell in row 2 is = to a cell in row 1 highlight both cells" and so on, so that if a cell in Row 3 is equal to a cell in row 2 etc. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please post some steps as to what you've already tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Two formulas, one for Row 1:

```
 =B1=B2
```

Then in the rest of the rows:

```
=OR(B2=B1,B2=B3)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. It works for duplicates in the same column but I need it to work if the duplicate is in the cell above but in any column.